# Spring boot shut down when I close the session

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, ssh

My Spring Boot Rest Api works veryy good, but I have problem with him.
When I'm closing the terminal SSH, my application rest shut down also.

What I should do ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Run in background

Comment: how to run in background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `nohup`

```
nohup yourcommandtolauncjava
```

Comment: nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

Answer (score 0):

You can start your spring application as systemd service. It helps in managing the service in several ways.

How to: [Setup systemd service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service)

Once the configuration is done, you can use it for starting, stopping and restarting the service. And it also provides a way to auto-restart the application when the service goes down for whatever reason or after the restart of the machine.

Usage:

```
service <app name> start
service <app name stop
service <app name> restart
```

Answer (score 0):

**nohup**

nohupyesno hang up Do not suspend means that if you are running a process and you feel that the process will not end when you exit the account, you can use thenohupCommand. This command can continue to run the corresponding process after you exit the account / close the terminal. ==After the command is run, it is the foreground process==

**eg: nobup java -jar xxx.jar &**

& Let the program run in the background

**eg:  java -jar xxx.jar &**